# To pass the row number to another column

Tags: r, tapply

I have a dataframe.

I need to find a minimum value in the 1st column for each value of the 2nd column. But I should return the value in the 3rd column from the same row as the minimum found in the 1st column.

The first part seems is solved by `tapply(1,2, min)`

But how to pass the same row to the 3rd column?

The more complicated task is when the minimum is not unique in the 1st column. Then I need to choose the first name (out of several) alphabetically and again to find the corresponding value from the same row from the 3rd column.

Comment: Sounds like you should get started on some code then

Comment: Where is your dataframe?

Comment: @Ari Belenkly It is better to show the dataset using `dput` ie. copy and paste the output of `dput(head(data,10))` in your post.  It is a little hard to know the structure of the dataset from the comments.

Comment: @ AriBelenkiy: you should give your feedback / accept / upvote helpful answers.

Comment: I am ready to acknowledge your help but when I vote up it requires 15 reputation which I don't have.

Comment: @Ari Belenkiy I updated with a function though repeated requests to provide a reproducible data was not fulfilled.

Comment: @Ari Belenkiy You should install devtools first. Check this link http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/README.html . Regarding the second comment, yes, it is possible to create a function using sapply, split etc., but those methods I guess would be slower compared to dplyr (or data.table) which can handle big datasets easily. If you encounter any troubles in installing, I can create another function using base R tools. I guess lynghonig's ave based solution is also great.

Comment: @Ari Belenkiy I created a new function using `base R`

Answer (score 1):

A reproducible example would be handy to fully understand your question.

However, I think you can use ave for this.

```
a<-c(1:10)
b<-c(rep(1,3),rep(2,4),rep(3,3))
c<-c(101:110)

df<-cbind(a,b,c)
```

which gives

```
df
      a b   c
[1,]  1 1 101
[2,]  2 1 102
[3,]  3 1 103
[4,]  4 2 104
[5,]  5 2 105
[6,]  6 2 106
[7,]  7 2 107
[8,]  8 3 108
[9,]  9 3 109
[10,] 10 3 110
```

So I am going to find the min of a my b and keep the corresponding c.

```
rows<-df[which(ave(df[,1],df[,2],FUN=function(x) x==min(x))==1),]
```

which gives

```
rows
     a b   c
[1,] 1 1 101
[2,] 4 2 104
[3,] 8 3 108
```

Comment: I think both answers might be right but I have difficulty since my data are "names" like here:                                                     name landmass zone area population
1    Afghanistan        5    1  648         16
2        Albania        3    1   29          3
3        Algeria        4    1 2388         20
4 American-Samoa        6    3    0          0
5        Andorra        3    1    0          0
6         Angola        4    2 1247          7

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear after reading the comments.

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    group_by(zone) %>%
    filter(population==min(population)) %>%
    #ungroup() %>% #if you don't need zone
    select(name)
 #    zone           name
 #  1    3 American-Samoa
 #  2    1        Andorra
 #  3    2         Angola
```

#### Update

```
 devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
 devtools::install_github("hadley/lazyeval")

 library(dplyr)
 library(lazyeval)

 fun2 <- function(grp, Column, grpDontShow=TRUE){ 
         stopifnot(is.numeric(df[,grp]) & Column %in% colnames(df))
         df1 <- df %>% 
                   group_by_(grp) %>%
                   filter_(interp(~x==min(x), x=as.name(Column)))%>%
                   arrange(name) %>%
                   filter(row_number()==1) %>%
                   select(name)     
        if(grpDontShow){
                ungroup(df1) %>%
                          select(name)
                 }
        else {
            df1
          }            
        }       

 fun2("zone", "population", TRUE)
 # Source: local data frame [3 x 1]

 #            name
 #1        Andorra
 #2         Angola
 #3 American-Samoa

  fun2("zone", "landmass", FALSE)
  #Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
  #Groups: zone

  #  zone           name
  #1    1        Albania
  #2    2         Angola
  #3    3 American-Samoa

   fun2("ozone", "landmass", FALSE)
   #Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , grp) : undefined columns selected

  fun2("name", "landmass", FALSE)
  #Error: is.numeric(df[, grp]) & Column %in% colnames(df) is not TRUE
```

#### Update2

If you need a function using `base R`

```
  funBase <- function(grp, Column, grpDontShow = TRUE) {
            stopifnot(is.numeric(df[, grp]) & Column %in% colnames(df))
            v1 <- c(by(df[, c(Column, "name")], list(df[, grp]),
                   FUN = function(x) sort(x[,2][x[, 1] == min(x[, 1],
                                                   na.rm = TRUE)])[1]))

             if (grpDontShow) {
               data.frame(name = v1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
             }
              else {
             setNames(data.frame(as.numeric(names(v1)),
                       v1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), c(grp, "name"))

            }
         }

   funBase("zone", "landmass")
   #            name
   #1        Albania
   #2         Angola
   #3 American-Samoa

  funBase("zone", "population", FALSE)
  #  zone           name
  #1    1        Andorra
  #2    2         Angola
  #3    3 American-Samoa
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(name = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", 
 "American-Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola"), landmass = c(5L, 3L, 
 4L, 6L, 3L, 4L), zone = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L), area = c(648L, 
 29L, 2388L, 0L, 0L, 1247L), population = c(16L, 3L, 20L, 0L, 
 0L, 7L)), .Names = c("name", "landmass", "zone", "area", "population"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
 "6"))
```

Comment: No, I need to choose the country with minimal population separately for every zone.

Comment: @AriBelenkiy It seems to me that what you said is what akrun demonstrated. Would you please rephrase what you mean? Alternatively, would you be able to provide a sample data and an expected outcome?

Comment: Thank you for editing the data. Actually I need a function that has two arguments: one (numeric) for "zone", another - for any other column where a minimal value exists (eg "population" or "landmass"). I also need to use stop function if one of the arguments is invalid with a warning.

Comment: Akrun, you are a great man. I feel it is right but I cannot ascertain it since I got the message: devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘devtools’.

Comment: To continue: I feel I like the second way that you and lynghonig showed more. Could you create a function that uses "sapply", "split" and "order" rather than "filter"? And again - what is the way to acknowledge your help? Which button must be clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> ddf
    col1 col2 col3
 1:    5    a    A
 2:    2    a    B
 3:    3    a    C
 4:    6    a    D
 5:    4    b    E
 6:    2    b    F
 7:    6    b    G
 8:    2    b    H
 9:    7    c    I
10:    2    c    J
11:    6    c    K
12:    4    c    L
13:    2    c    M
> 
> sapply(split(ddf, ddf$col2), 
         function(x) {x = x[order(x$col3),]; x$col3[which.min(x$col1)]})
a b c 
B F J 
Levels: A B C D E F G H I J K L M
```

Using @lynghonig's data:

```
> sapply(split(ddf, ddf$b), 
         function(x) {x = x[order(x$c),]; x$c[which.min(x$a)]})
  1   2   3 
101 104 108
```

With OP's data (from comments):

```
> sapply(split(ddf, ddf$landmass), function(x) {x = x[order(x$zone),]; x$zone[which.min(x$name)]})
3 4 5 6 
1 1 1 3
```

Comment: Why do you need to "order" the variable c?

Comment: order c to get the right one (alphabetically) of there are more than 1 minimum values.